# Gnuplot - Black on White Palette

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to find/create a color palette that would be the inverse of the "gray palette", as shown in here:

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pm3dcolors.html

that is, the color is white at 0 and becomes darker as it goes to 1.

Can someone help me locate or create a palette like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gnuplot> set palette gray negative
gnuplot> test palette
```

[image]